# Use only specifics exit nodes for a site

Tags: exit-relays

In `torrc`, using `AllowDotExit` and `MapAddress` I can specify only one exit node for "mysite.com".
For example with:

> AllowDotExit 1
>
> MapAddress mysite.com mysite.com.mynode.exit

With `ExitNodes` and `StrictNodes` I specify ten exit nodes but for all sites. For example with:

> StrictNodes 1
>
> ExitNodes mynode1, mynode2, ... mynode10

---

I want to arrange that for "mysite.com", Tor uses only the ten exit nodes that I specify in torrc but allow other sites to use all exit nodes.

How can I this?

Comment: Note that you don't need `AllowDotExit` to use `.exit` with `MapAddress` and enabling `AllowDotExit` is *extremely* dangerous and shouldn't *ever* be done.

Answer (score 2):

It's not implemented in original Tor as far as I know. The only way to achive this functionality is using the Stem-controlled circuit built by hand.

Comment: +1 Would you care to elaborate on your answer. I have exact same interest as OP, namely to specify for instance `ExitNodes {de},{nl}`, but only for specific URLs or family of URLs... Tx